# Launching two processes at once

Tags: python

Ok, so I want to have a script that will run an install process. One of the parts of this is installing Microsoft Office products. I want to launch a Microsoft installer and then programmatically (currently using the Python library 'Pywinauto') insert keys and press buttons.

However, the program stops executing when it reaches the launch of the Office installer, and only resumes once it closes.

Is there anyway to have like, two separate "paths" the program takes, at the same time? Launch the Office installer and while that is still open, have another path insert the correct code into it?

EDIT: Here's some pseudocode, I figured it might end up being helpful.

```
if x == blah:
    Path 1:
    subprocess.call("installer.exe")
    Path 2 (at exactly the same moment):
    pywinautoify-insert serial key, clicky buttons
    Both end at the same time, merge back into standard program code
```

Comment: Chances are you'll find this task a lot easier with the free `inno setup` (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It has quite some features regarding the creation of installers (and you can script it if you need to).

Comment: When you launch the install process you are already spawning a separate process, that runs indipendently from yours, the problem is that probably you are launching it in a way that waits for the child process to terminate before resuming execution; question is: how are you starting the install process? By the way, if you want to run a silent install you can just use the correct switches for the setup, and often even customize the install settings with an MSI transform, without resorting to this kind of hacks.

Comment: I am starting the install process by doing subprocess.calls of the main executable. There are switches to make everything automatic and silent?

Comment: It depends from the product you are installing.

Comment: Microsoft Office, in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to spawn a process without waiting for it you can simply use `os.spawnl` with the `os.P_NOWAIT` flag.

But the fundamental error is trying to automate an installation process in this way. Almost all installers (especially if they are installers for "big" products) allow silent, automated installation to simplify the life of system administrators. The usual switch for silent installs is `/q` or `-q`, and you often can specify the settings for the installation in some way (with a special configuration file or with an MSI transform, for example).

In particular, for Office 2007 and 2010 you can read [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630736%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd630736.aspx).